# Bounding volume of cell in complement of zero set

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, real-algebraic-geometry, nonlinear-optimization

I am given an integer polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Z}[X_1, \ldots, X_n]$ of bounded degree and bounded coefficient size. The polynomial's zero set partitions $\mathbb{R}^n$ into cells. What I am looking for is a lower bound on the volume of the cells (in terms of dimension, coefficient size and degree of $f$).

Do there exist results of this kind? And, if yes, where can I learn about them?

Comment: That is an interesting question.  Can you say a little more?  Are you trying to bound the least volume of a cell?  Are you assuming that $f$ is smooth, i.e., the partial derivatives generate the unit ideal (after tensoring with $\mathbb{R}$, say)?

Comment: @JasonStarr: I do try to bound the volume of the least cell. If the polynomial is smooth I cannot say because I don't understand your notion of smoothness.

Comment: If you consider the same problem with real coefficients instead of integer coefficients, then, in coefficient space, the "limits" where you find "zero volume" will all be for singular polynomials, i.e., the discriminant locus.  So, now you can try to do a differential analysis of the volume of the cell near the singular point as you perturb from a generic member of the discriminant locus.  The asymptotics will presumably involve the discriminant polynomial.  So, presumably, this will reduce to bounding the discriminant polynomial on your original coefficients, which is easy.